# How to count the number of dimensions in Swift array

Tags: swift, multidimensional-array

I have a `[Any]` as the input and would like to know the dimension of the array. For example,

```
var a = [[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]]
```

The dimension is 3 (3 layer array).

The way I'm using is to use `type` to convert it to type and count the number of "Array".

```
"\(type(of: a))" 
$R16: String = "Array<Array<Array<Int>>>"
```

I wonder is there any better way to achieve my goal.

Comment: refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33664208/calculate-the-number-of-dimensions-of-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-swift

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate the number of dimensions of a multi-dimensional array in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33664208/calculate-the-number-of-dimensions-of-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-swift)

Comment: Try different approach on result of 'a.removeAll()' .-)      type(of: ) or
Mirror(reflecting: ).subjectType is the only way ... You could play with Mirror, but there is no simpler solution, at least not with public API

Comment: `extension Collection {
    var levels: Int { ((first as? [Any])?.levels ?? 0) + 1 }
}`

Comment: @LeoDabus check with empty multidimensional array ...

Comment: What do you mean by empty multidimensional array? `var a:[Any] = [[]]` returns 2 for me

Comment: @LeoDabus var a = [[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]]  // 3 dimensional array, a.removeAll() , still 3 dimensional array, as reported with type(of:a), but a.levels == 1

Comment: @LeoDabus var b:[Any] = [[]], b.removeAll() ... STILL THE SAME TYPE! but b.level == 1

Comment: @LeoDabus let a:[[Any]] = [] is  'two dimensional' with type Array<Array<Any>> with .level == 1

Comment: The real issue is why would you need that. I think you should edit your question and show what is your goal. Forget about array of `Any`. I've been coding in Swift for 5 and a half years and never needed that.